# AngularJS 1.5 not display in IE11

Tags: angularjs

I have a non-CLI AugularJS program that is not displaying in IE 11.
I have added the following into my index.html:

```
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/core.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/web-animations-js/web-animations.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/intl/dist/intl.min.js"></script>
```

What else do I need to do get my program to display in Internet Explorer?
In IE, I am getting Syntax errors on these lines in my various JS files:

```
socketService.connect().then((socket) => {});
...
new_time.time_list = Array.from(new Array(new_time.max),....);
...
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope,$location) {
...
```

I saw references to using import and require() to add core-js and other poly fills, but the syntax didn't work for me in AngularJS 1.5. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please post the errors you're getting. And can you expand on "Didn't work for you" when you use import or require? Also, you may want to take a look at [the Angular IE Compatibility Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie) if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that **IE11** doesn't support the **javascript** version you are using. As you described in the code bellow, you are using arrow functions, which [**IE11** doesn't support](https://caniuse.com/#search=arrow). You are also using other **ES6** features like `Array.from` which [is not supported either](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Array_static_methods).

```
socketService.connect().then((socket) => {});
...
new_time.time_list = Array.from(new Array(new_time.max),....);
...
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope,$location) {
...
```

In resume, **IE11** doesn't have a decent support for modern **javascript**. What you can do to port your code to run in such archaic browser is transpiling **ES6** into **ES5** code using [babeljs](https://babeljs.io/) which is very common nowadays [2018]. There is also, [es5-shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) and [es6-shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es6-shim) to extend the api level of older browser but **ES6+** syntax specifics still needs to be transpiled into **ES5** syntax.